# Update ActiveRow from textbox excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Some help please - trying to keep it simple

I have a UserForm which updates text boxes from selection in ComboBox. I would like to be able to change these populated boxes, and then with Update command, change the values in the sheet and then clear the form

[image: Form Image]

[image: Sheet1 Image]

I've been able to create the UserForm that adds the data, but i struggle to let VBA select the active cell and active row from the control box...????

Once I can get VBA to the correct AvtiveCell, i can use offset and change/add as needed

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me
        .TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 2)
        .TextBox2.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 3)
        .TextBox3.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 4)
        .TextBox4.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 5)
        .TextBox5.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 6)
        .TextBox6.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 7)
        .TextBox7.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 8)
        .TextBox8.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 9)
        .TextBox9.Value = Sheet1.Cells(.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 10)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub EditAddButton_Click()
    EditAdd
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you paste your current userform code? We need to see how far you've already got.

Comment: Hi Chris, heres the code sofar

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have the autopopulation done. Now you need to add code to your EditAdd click sub. Presumably you want to replace the cell values on the sheet with the contents of those in the userform.

What have you tried so far? I would simply try reversing the assignments! For example, in that sub, do something like this:

```
Private Sub EditAddButton_Click()
    Dim ComplaintNum as Integer
    ComplaintNum = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2
    With Sheet1
        .cells(ComplaintNum, 2) = TextBox1.Value
        ' etc down the list
    End With
End Sub
```

I have not tested this - but give it a go and play around with it. You'll also need to handle adding new rows, but I won't write that for you yet :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, Will try it, this is what i use to insert new row. any improvements? Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1

ws.Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = DateReceivedBox.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = ViaBox.Value

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = FromTextbox.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = Location1Box.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = Location2Box.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = RegNumberBox.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = VehicleMakeBox.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = VehicleColorBox.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = CommentsBox.Value
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+R[-1]C+1"
Range("A1").Select
Unload Me
NewComplaintForm.Show

End Sub

Comment: Given that it's hard to read code in the comments, I wouldn't immediately tell if this insertion code works or not - however if it's working for you, great. One improvement though: you almost never need to "select" cells in code. Don't select then use ActiveCell. Just refer to the cell directly.

Comment: For example, instead of saying Cells(1,1).Select / ActiveCell.Value="Hello" - just say Cells(1,1).value="Hello".